# ¿Como mover una imagen dentro de la etiqueta img?

Tags: html, css

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy maquetando un email donde abajo debe ir una imagen de fondo, pero no logro hacer bajar la imagen, por decir lo que quiero es que el contenedor en este caso

se quede donde mismo y mover solo la imagen para alinearla. actualmente la imagen se encuentra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que espero es mover la imagen para que quede asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que empate con el fondo del email.

El codigo contenedor de esa imagen es el siguiente:

```html
<p><img src="footer-lquid.png" width="100%" /></p>
```

y como nota, se hacer esto con background: url... y despues background-position y etc, pero en este caso no puedo usar esto.
Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda :)

Comment: Por favor provee un [mcve] para poder ayudarte

Comment: Como lo dicen más arriba, no das nada de información que nos pueda ayudar a entender el problema mas que la etiqueta img :/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar así

```css
.imagen-footer
{
bottom: 0; /* O lo que tu quieras*/ 
position: absolute; } 
.form
{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="form">
<input placeholder="email">
<br>
<button>Enviar</button>
</div>
<div class="background">
<img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/white-rectangle-mosaic-tiles-texture-background-long-wide-picture-picture-id1142405244" style="width: 100vw; height: 4em;">
</div>
```

Creo que es a esto a lo que te refieres, de no serlo dímelo